# Filtering results of querying a model based on ids of related ManyToMany another Model ids

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have 2 models

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    ques_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Tag_name = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ques_id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

searlizers.py

```
class TagSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = '__all__'

class QuestionSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

This is my searilzers class.
I want the response like

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "QUES 1",
  "tags": [{
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Abcd" 
  }]
}
```

what will be query to get Fetch 10 questions, given some input tag ids
e.g Tag_id = 1 or 2 or 3.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: can you show your serializers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `tags` field as another serializer data to your `QuestionSerializer`.

Your `QuestionSerializer` code should look like that:

```
class QuestionSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Tag_name = TagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you want exactly `tags` name in response, you can specify `SerializerMethodField` like that:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    get_tags(self, instance):
        return TagSerializer(instance.Tag_name, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('ques_id', 'name', 'tags')
```

Comment: How should my Tag searlizer look ?

Answer (score 0):

**First**: I would suggest that you refactor your `Question` Model, since it has a `ques_id`, and I think it is considered a duplicate *(since Django already creates an id field by default)*

Then You need to change your `ManyToManyField`'s name to `tags`, and `makemigrations`, then `migrate`

```
class Question(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
# run make migrations
python manage.py makemigrations <<<YOUR QUESTIONS APP NAME>>>
# It will prompt you to check if you change the many to many relationship say yes
Did you rename question.Tag_name to question.tags (a ManyToManyField)? [y/N] y
# Then Run migrate
python manage.py migrate
```

**Second**: Update your `QuestionSerializers` to make the tags field serialize the relation

```
class QuestionSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializers(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

This way you make your code cleaner. And you are good to go.

---

#### Answer Updated (Filtering, and Pagination)

Now if you wanted to filter questions based on provided tag ids.

You need to use `PageNumberPagination` for your view, and for filtering use `DjangoFilterBackend`.

> I recommend you to make them the default of DRF settings.
>
> Make sure you have `django-filter` installed.

```
# In your settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
    ),
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}
```

Now create your custom filter

```
# Inside filters.py
import re

import django_filters

from questions.models import Question


class QuestionsFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet):
    tags = django_filters.CharFilter(field_name='tags__id', method='tags_ids_in')

    def tags_ids_in(self, qs, name, value):
        ids_list = list(map(lambda id: int(id), filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), re.split(r'\s*,\s*', value))))
        return qs.filter(**{f"{name}__in": ids_list}).distinct()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('tags',)
```

Now use `ListAPIView` to list your questions

```
class QuestionsListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Question.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializers
    filter_class = QuestionsFilterSet
```

Now if you hit

```
http://<PATH_TO_VIEW>?tags=1,2,3
```

You will receive all Questions that have tag id 1, 2, or 3.
and all of them will be paginated 10 results at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to write a field `tags` like this in your `QuestionSerializers`

```
class QuestionSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = TagSerializers(source='Tag_name', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'tags')
```

It will give you response like this

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "QUES 1",
  "tags": [{
     "id": 1,
     "name": "Abcd" 
  }]
}
```

Your query to fetch on the basis of tags will be like this

```
Question.objects.filter(Tag_name__in=[1, 2, 4])
```